# ICommand not working in Silverlight User control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a `UserControlBase` with a grid. The grid contains a column with an Action.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                 <Button Style="{StaticResource DataGridButton}"  Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource NewsViewModel}, Path=ModifyNewsCommand}" Content="Modify" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My problem is with my `Command`. It is throwing me Technical Error which is my first problem, I don't know how to make this application throw me the real error message.

In the code behind of my user control I registered the events:

```
protected void RegisterMessages()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "NewNewsBtn_Click", NewNewsBtn_Click);
    Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "ModifyNewsBtn_Click", ModifyNewsBtn_Click);
}
```

And in my constructor:

```
public NewsWindow(int underlyingId)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.RegisterMessages();
    viewModel = new NewsViewModel(underlyingId);
    ucNewsPanel.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

My view model (NewsViewModel)

```
public ICommand ModifyNewsCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<string>(e =>
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(string.Empty, "ModifyNewsBtn_Click");
        });
    }
}
```

What's weird here is that my `NewNewsBtn` is working, while my `ModifyNewsBtn` is not.

This button is outside the grid so it might make a difference on why it is working.

```
<Button x:Name="NewNewsBtn" MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="100" Command="{Binding Path=NewNewsCommand}" Content="Add New" />
```

Comment: Why do you use a StaticResource in your Binding instead of just accessing the DataContext? Looks to me like this is the cause for your Button not working.

Comment: I guess this part is wrong **Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource NewsViewModel}, Path=ModifyNewsCommand}"**

Comment: @Martin - If remove the StaticResource and just the leave the Path, it is not working. It is not throwing me error but it is not entering the method.

Comment: And I guess I know why. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataGrid will be bound to some collection, having a row per each item. Now the item is the DataContext for a row. What you need to do is bind your "Modify"-button to the parent DataContext. If you are using silverlight5 you can use an `AncestorBinding`:

```
<Button
    Content="Modify"
    Command="{Binding
        Path=DataContext.ModifyNewsCommand,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks okay:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DataGridButton}" Content="Modify" 
  Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource NewsViewModel}, Path=ModifyNewsCommand}"/>
```

**But you set your viewModel in code.** Am I right that you create `StaticResource` in XAML? If it is, then just delete setting `DataContext` from code-behind cause the following row `Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource NewsViewModel}, Path=ModifyNewsCommand}"` will see in the another instance of your viewModel. (cause you've create two instances of `NewsViewModel` as a `StaticResource` and in code-behind)

**Update:**
*I needed the DataContext in code behind as I am passing a parameter to my view model. Any way I can do that if I removed it from code behind?*
Then you should delete `StaticResource` from Binding of `Command`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DataGridButton}" Command="{Binding ModifyNewsCommand}" 
                                                                    Content="Modify"/>
```

Cause you are referencing to another instance of `NewsViewModel`.

Comment: I needed the `DataContext` in code behind as I am passing a parameter to my view model. Any way I can do that if I removed it from code behind?

Comment: the updated answer won't work. It can't find the view model.